# awk / sed / etc. concatenating colums in one file

Tags: shell-script, command-line, sed, awk

I wonder what is a simpler way to do this:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9$10$11$12$13$14$15$16}'  file.in > file.out
```

which is simply speaking " concatenate columns 9 to 16 by removing tabs in-between"

Merged columns 9-16 become "Notes" so may include whitespaces.

As of today there are 16 columns but this may evolve in more/less if required. Eventually column 9 (concatenated 9-16) becomes "notes" field.

Cheers,
Xi

Comment: Can the input file contain white spaces?

Comment: Yes, merged columns 9-16 become "Notes" so may include whitespaces.

Comment: Then how are "columns" defined? Your `awk` solution fails if your fields can contain whitespace. Is your input file tab-separated?

Comment: Yes it is tab separated. Sorry,  I thought that including "\t" between columns 1-9 reveals that this is tab separated file.

Comment: @xi100f no, that just means that some of your output columns will be tab-separated. For a tab-separated input file, awk needs `-F '\t'`.

Comment: doesn't awk by default separates field by white-space which includes tabs? I just checked on sample file and it works without `-F '\t'`

Comment: @spasic yes, but if one of the fields contains whitespace, it will be considered two fields. Compare `printf 'one\ttwo a b\tthree' | awk '{print $2}'` and `printf 'one\ttwo a b\tthree' | awk -F"\t" '{print $2}'`

Comment: oh ok, didn't know that..

Comment: @terdon - thanks for example that was worth more than thousand words!

Comment: @xi100f you're very welcome. By the way, if one of the answers below solved your problem, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
paste <(cut -f 1-8 file) <(cut -f9- file | tr -d '\t')
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I love simplicity and portability of this.

Comment: Nice an simple, can be a problem for big files though, as `sed` and `awk` work per line, while`paste` needs to buffer the contents in RAM. But that should be a rare limitation.

Comment: @Fiximan Are you sure? As far as I can tell, GNU `paste` only buffers a single line from each open file.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs Not 100%, I haven't looked into the source code - however I did experience problems with `paste` on two large files (with long lines, too), where an analogous `awk` script did not fail. Long time ago and GB-sized files, so I don't have the details anymore, but I came out with the assumption that this was the reason. Might have been a wrong guess though.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a few lines of tably separated values, generated thusly:

```
% perl -E 'say join "\t", 1..8 for 1..3'
```

The various columns can then be dealt with as necessary via the appropriate [flags](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlrun.pod) and [variables](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlvar.pod) and [functions](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlfunc.pod) available in Perl.

```
% perl -E 'say join "\t", 1..8 for 1..3' \
| perl -pale '$_=join "\t", @F[0..3], join "", @F[4..7] if $. > 1' 
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
1   2   3   4   5678
1   2   3   4   5678
%
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, many ways. I have tested the following two on a file created by:

```
perl -le 'next if $.==1; for(1..20){print join "\t",1..20 }' > file
```

That's a file with 20 lines and 20 tab-separated columns.

1. Perl

   ```
   perl -F'\t' -ale '$"="\t";print "@F[0..7]",@F[8..$#F]' file
   ```

   Note that this joins all the fields from the 10th to the end. If you only want to join 9 to 16, use this instead:

   ```
   perl -F'\t' -ale '$"="\t"; print "@F[0..7]", @F[8..15], "\t@F[16..$#F]"' file
   ```
2. awk

   ```
   awk -F'\t' 'NR>1{
                   for(i=1;i<9;i++){
                       printf "%s\t",$i
                   }
                   for(i=9;i<=NF;i++){
                       printf "%s",$i
                   }print "" 
               }' file
   ```

   As before, this will join all columns after the 10th. If you only want to join 9 to 16, use this instead:

   ```
   awk -F'\t' 'NR>1{
                   for(i=1;i<9;i++){
                       printf "%s\t",$i
                   }
                   for(i=9;i<=16;i++){
                       printf "%s",$i
                   }
                   for(i=17;i<=NF;i++){
                       printf "\t%s", $i
                   }
                   print ""
               }' file
   ```

Granted, the `awk` solutions aren't very short, but at least you don't need to specify all the fields by hand.

Answer (score 2):

#### Python alternative

```
$ cat file | python -c "import sys
for line in sys.stdin: l=line.rstrip('\r\n').split('\t'); print('\t'.join(l[:9]) + ''.join(l[9:]))
"
```

#### sed alternative

```
s/(([^\t]*\t){8})/\1\n/
h
s/[^\n]*\n//
s/\t//g
G
s/([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n.*/\2\1/
```

Usage example:

```
$ sed -r "s/(([^\t]*\t){8})/\1\n/;h;s/[^\n]*\n//;s/\t//g;G;s/([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n.*/\2\1/" file
```

Explanation:

Suppose that `file` is

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l
```

The separator in `file` is tab.

1. `sed` reads the current line.

   - pattern space is `a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l`
2. `s/(([^\t]*\t){8})/\1\n/` splits the line in two parts.

   - pattern space is `a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   \ni   j   k   l`
3. `h` stores pattern space in hold space.

   - pattern space is `a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   \ni   j   k   l`
   - hold space is `a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   \ni   j   k   l`
4. `s/[^\n]*\n//` removes the first part in pattern space.

   - pattern space is `i   j   k   l`
   - hold space is `a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   \ni   j   k   l`
5. `s/\t//g` removes tabs in pattern space.

   - pattern space is `ijkl`
   - hold space is `a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   \ni   j   k   l`
6. `G` appends `\n` and hold space to the pattern space.

   - pattern space is `ijkl\na   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   \ni   j   k   l`
   - hold space is `a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   \ni   j   k   l`
7. `s/([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n.*/\2\1/` splits the pattern space and replace it with the second and the first parts without `\n`.

   - pattern space is `a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   ijkl`
   - hold space is `a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   \ni   j   k   l`
8. `sed` prints the pattern space.

It is possible do modify the code and remove tabs in the middle columns:

```
s/(([^\t]*\t){3})(([^\t]*\t){4})(.*)/\1\n\3\n\5/
h
s/[^\n]*\n([^\n]*)\n.*/\1/
s/\t//g
G
s/([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n(.*)/\2\1\4/
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `sed` (assuming the fields are tab delimited in the input):

```
sed 's/\t//9g'
```

Deletes the 9th to last tab characters on each line.

If there are more than 16 fields in the input and you don't want the extra ones:

```
cut -f 1-16 | sed 's/\t//9g'
```

Answer (score 1):

awk:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{for (i=10; i<=NF; i++) $9 = $9 " " $i; NF = 9; print}' file
```

Fields 10 to the end are appended to field 9, then the number of fields is limited to the first 9, and the line is printed using tab as the output field separator.

I assume you want the concatenated fields to be separated with a space.
If not, change `$9 " " $i` to `$9 $i`